# How to use ContentsManager for Jupyter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I've read about Jupyter ContentsManager but have no idea how to use it and the documentation is really bad. What should I do? Where do I run it and how do I connect it to my Jupyter Environment and notebooks?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with ContentsManager?

Comment: The documentation is [here](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developers/contents.html).

Comment: @krassowski First of all: How do I tell jupyter to use my own ContentsManager?

Comment: See answer below. Though a chance is that you do not need a custom ContentsManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To swap the contents manager in JupyterLab 3.0+ that is running on the new jupyter server (this is the default way of doing things, but if you are running on JupyterHub it might still use the old notebook server), create a `jupyter_server_config.py` file; you can auto-generate it in appropriate location using:

```
jupyter server --generate-config
```

and set the contents manager class to you own manager:

```
c.ServerApp.contents_manager_class = "python.module.for.your.ContentsManagerSubclass"
```

This option is described on the list of [configuration options](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/other/full-config.html) of jupyter server.

(alternatively, you could use a json file). For older JupyterLab versions, or if for some weird reason you are using the old notebook you will want to use `jupyter_notebook_config.py` where this option was named `c.NotebookApp.contents_manager_class`. You can read more on this topic [here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/3896#issuecomment-367004570) - although the examples reference the old notebook way of doing things so you would need to updated accordingly.

You may also be interested to learn how [jupytext hot swaps the content managers](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/blob/4ae9263d3cb94fea9880a6b1676af81e91092399/docs/install.md#jupytexts-contents-manager) reacting to user settings, see the code [here](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/blob/4ae9263d3cb94fea9880a6b1676af81e91092399/jupytext/__init__.py#L23-L68).

Comment: Thanks for all that information. And do I need to do any extra steps when running jupyter so my custom config is used and not the default one?

Comment: No. Note the config needs to be in a standard location that is recognised by jupyter. If you generate it by the command above it will be there already; otherwise, see `jupyter --paths` and [read the documentation here](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html) and [here](https://jupyter-server.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operators/configuring-extensions.html?highlight=paths#configuring-extensions).